# Showing data on Matlab GUI which is continuously being updated in a separate Matlab function

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a function in Matlab which is getting continuous sensor values from a hardware. It gives a flag when new values are available and we can update the variables holding these values. Following is a dummy function to mimic what this function is doing.

```
function example( )
% Example function to describe functionality of NatNetOptiTrack

% Hardware initialization,    
% Retriving real time information continuously

for i = 1:100   %in real time this loop runs for ever
   data = rand(3,6);
   % Send the updated data to gui in each iteration
end

end
```

i have made a gui using guide as shown in the figure:

[image]

So the data to be displayed is a 3x6 matrix with columns corresponding to X Y Z Roll Pitch and Yaw values while rows correspond to Objects.

I want to show the continuously updated values from this function on the gui. Is there a way i can initialize gui inside my example function and update the output value by using the handles inside my loop. I tried copying the gui code inside the example function as a script, it was able to initialize but was not recognizing the handles.
Also i want to show the current values on command window when i press the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch the GUI and then run the function, you should be able to get the handles to the controls on the GUI provided that you make the GUI figure handle visible and set its tag/name to something appropriate.  In GUIDE,  open the Property Inspector for the GUI and set the **HandleVisibility** property to **on**, and the **Tag** property to **MyGui** (or some other name).  Then in your `example.m` file do the following

```
function example( )
    % Example function to describe functionality of NatNetOptiTrack

    % get the handle of the GUI
    hGui = findobj('Tag','MyGui');

    if ~isempty(hGui)
        % get the handles to the controls of the GUI
        handles = guidata(hGui);
    else
        handles = [];
    end


    % Hardware initialization,    
    % Retriving real time information continuously

    for i = 1:100   %in real time this loop runs for ever
       data = rand(3,6);

       % update the GUI controls
       if ~isempty(handles)

           % update the controls
           % set(handles.yaw,…);
           % etc.
       end

       % make sure that the GUI is refreshed with new content
       drawnow();
    end
end
```

An alternative is to copy the `example` function code into your GUI - the hardware initializations could occur in the `_OpeningFcn` of your GUI and you could create a (periodic) timer to communicate with the hardware and get the data to display on the GUI.

As for displaying the current data when pressing the GUI button, you can easily do this by writing the contents of the GUI controls to the command line/window with `fprintf`.  You will though need to make your `example` function interruptible so that the push button can interrupt that continuously running loop.  You can do this by either adding a `pause` call (for a certain number of milliseconds) that gets executed at the end of each iteration of your loop, or just make use of the `drawnow` call from above (that is why I placed it outside of the `if` statement - so that it will be called on each iteration of your loop.

Try the above and see what happens!